# TS2559: Type '{ children: Element[]; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to use `react-router-dom` by `React` with `TypeScript`. I have a typescript error in `<Router>` at `Home.jsx`.

### Error

- Home.tsx

  ```
  Type '{ children: Element[]; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.TS2559(9)
  ```
- App.tsx

```
import React from 'react'
import Home from './pages/Home'


function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Home />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

- Home.tsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { Button, TitleDesc } from '../components/Index'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import Router from '../router'

const Home: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <div>
          <div>Hii</div>
          <div>
            <Link to='/login'><Button color='green'>Login</Button></Link>
            <Link to='/register'><Button color='blue'>Register</Button></Link>
          </div>
        </div>
        <TitleDesc title='Hi' desc='Hi' />
      </Router>
    </>
  )
}

export default Home
```

- router.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import Login from './pages/Login'
import Register from './pages/Register'
import Home from './pages/Home'

const Router = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
        <Route exact path='/Login' component={Login} />
        <Route exact path='/Register' component={Registerl} />
        <Route component={() => <h1>204 No Content</h1>} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}

export default Router
```

Comment: Please state in which file the error is occurring possibly with the line number too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of you don't call `{props.children}` in the `router.tsx`. Change it to bellow code will remove the error:

```
const Router = : React.FunctionComponent (props) => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
        <Route exact path='/Login' component={Login} />
        <Route exact path='/Register' component={Registerl} />
        <Route component={() => <h1>204 No Content</h1>} />
        {props.children}
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}
```

But logically it doesn't need to do something as you did. Because your `Router` will handle the routes and you don't need to use it again in the `Home`. So instead of using `Home` in `App`, transform it to use `Router` in your `App`. Thus your code can change to this:

**App.tsx**

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Router/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

**Home.tsx**

```
const Home: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <>
        <div>
          <div>Hii</div>
          <div>
            <Link to='/login'><Button color='green'>Login</Button></Link>
            <Link to='/register'><Button color='blue'>Register</Button></Link>
          </div>
        </div>
        <TitleDesc title='Hi' desc='Hi' />
    </>
  )
}

export default Home
```

**Router.tsx**

This component won't change.

Answer (score 0):

I think `Router` only accepts a single child. You have two: `div` and `TitleDesc`. Wrap those in a `<>` and it should be fine:

```
const Home: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <> {/* <-- new wrapper */ }
          <div>
            <div>Hii</div>
            <div>
              <Link to='/login'><Button color='green'>Login</Button></Link>
              <Link to='/register'><Button color='blue'>Register</Button></Link>
            </div>
          </div>
          <TitleDesc title='Hi' desc='Hi' />
        </> {/* <-- new wrapper */}
      </Router>
    </>
  )
}
```